# Sharepoint list Dynamic Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spquery

I need to query a list in SharePoint where the columns may be added in the future.
For instance at the moment I have the following columns
Name, Job, interests, address
I want to be able to query this string dynamically using a parameter from the browser so if columns are added in the future I don’t have to change the code but just the parameter.
The address may look like this www.contoso.com/sites/mypage.aspx?property=Interests
And the code something on the line of this:

```
var SiteParameter = Request.QueryString["property"];

var ItemsFromList = from item in ListItems where item[try to put the parameter in here] select item;
```

I use SPmetal to get the list details, so if I press item. Visual Studio2010 will return the columns within the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be easier without SPMetal.

```
var qy = new SPQuery();
qy.Query =
    "<Where><Eq>" +
        "<FieldRef Name=`" + siteParameter + "'/>" +
        // You may have to worry about the type of the field here, too.
        "<Value Type='Text'>" + desiredValue + "</Value>" + 
    "</Eq></Where>";
var itemCollection = myList.GetItems(qy);
```

Comment: Thanks, Just another question, how do you declare the myList?

Comment: `var myList = myWeb.Lists["YourListName"]` should be fine if you know the list exists.